# Does Linear Discriminant Analysis make dimensionality reduction before classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm trying to understand what LDA exactly does when used as a classifier, i've understood how the dimensionality reduction works and i've understood that the classification task is carried out with the application of Bayes' theorem, but i still can't figure out if LDA executes both operation when used as a classification algorithm.

It's correct to say that LDA as a classifier executes by itself dimensionality reduction and then applies Bayes' theorem for classification?

If that makes any difference, i've used LDA in Python from the sklearn library.

Comment: What do you mean by "both operation"?  What does "executes by itself" mean?  Are you distinguishing between what is done at training time vs what is done at test time?

Comment: Sorry, i will try to better explain myself; i was wondering exactly what happens in the training phase, in particular if dimensionality reduction is performed even when the alghoritm is used for classification.